# Ckeditor issue with drupal

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor

I don't know this is a programming question but I have been advised to ask here (apologies if not appropriate).[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf4Rk.png)

Using Drupal 7.39, Win 8.1

When you edit any web page some functions in the editor (CKeditor) don't work - see screenshot. The screen has a white overlay for a second or so then nothing happens. Wondering whether there are any known problems with Ckeditor doing this in drupal sites?

Ckeditor used to work fine but I suspect one of the security updates (for modules) caused the problem.

Comment: It might be a javascript problem. Do you have the same issue with all web browsers? I remember some olders version (v3 and older) of the ckeditor.js libraries not working well with some ckeditor plugins on IE11.
You should check in the dev console of your web browser if there are any javascript error when you click these options and report here the error message.
Also give us the ckeditor.js version you are using.

Comment: It happens on IE, Mozilla & Chrome. The version of CKEditor installed is - "WYSIWYG HTML editor 7.x-1.16 Includes: CKEditor". I will look into the javascript errors. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - it has turned out to be a javascript problem, diagnosed with Mozilla dev.